# НОД чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: python, алгоритм, олимпиада, числа-фибоначчи, теория-чисел

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять в чём ошибка.

Как известно, последовательность Фибоначчи определяется следующим образом:

F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(n) = F(n-1)+F(n-2) (для всех n > 1).
По заданным n и m вычислить самый общий делитель чисел F(n) и F(m).

Вводимые данные данные:
Каждая строка является отдельным тестом и содержит два целых числа n и m (1 ≤ n, m ≤ 10^18). Число тестов не превышает 1000

Исходные данные:
Для каждого теста в отдельной строке вывести значение НОД(F(n),F(m)), вычисленное по модулю 10^8.

> ```
> Вводимые данные :                                        Исходные данные:
> 2 3                                                      1
> 1 1                                                      1
> 100 200                                                  61915075
> ```

[Ссылка на задание (там можно проверить правильность кода(на украинском языке))](https://www.e-olymp.com/uk/problems/2421)

Во-первых, программа точно не будет проходить по времени. Можно ли как-то её ускорить?
Во-вторых, сайт с заданием наотрез не хочет принимать код, то есть, не проходит ни один из тестов. Пытался разобраться с правильностью вводом данных несколько часов, и ни к чему не пришёл, кроме как к while True

Вот мой код :

```
import math
def fibonacci(n):
    fib1 = 1 #0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34
    fib2 = 1
    i = 0
    while i < n - 2:
        fib_sum = fib1 + fib2
        fib1 = fib2
        fib2 = fib_sum
        i = i + 1
    return fib2
cou=0
while True:
    m, k = map(int, input().split())
    print(math.gcd(fibonacci(m), fibonacci(k)) % 10**8)
```

Comment: *программа точно не будет проходить по времени. Можно ли как-то её ускорить?* Да запросто. Просто не надо вычислять каждый раз число с самого начала...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ввод без счётчика можно сделать так:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    n, m = map(int, line.split())
    ...
```

Других ошибок в коде я не вижу. Трудность только со временем работы. Долго ли будет вычисляться `fibonacci(10 ** 18)`? Если ваш компьютер делает один миллиард итераций цикла в секунду (а он работает медленнее, но всё же), то вам нужно `10^18 / 10^9 секунд = 32.5 года`.

Даже если вы готовы ждать 33 года (33000 лет для тысячи тестов), у вас нет достаточно памяти чтобы хранить `fibonacci(10 ** 18)`. По [формуле Бине](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5) оценим число бит для этого числа: `10**18 * log2((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2) = 6.9e+17 бит = 80820396 Gb`.

Плохие новости кончились.

В [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1347872/416121) [Sunny Cove](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/464000/sunny-cove) есть ключевая идея решения: `НОД(fib(n), fib(m)) = fib(НОД(n, m))`. Смотрите [свойства чисел Фибоначчи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

Нам нужно посчитать `fib(n)` для числа `n <= 10^18`. Хотя НОД уже вычислен, он может быть равен большему из чисел. В этом смысле задача проще не стала. В уже упомянутых свойствах есть интересное матричное равенство:

> ```
> / 1 1 \ n   / fib(n+1) fib(n)   \
> |     |   = |                   |
> \ 1 0 /     \ fib(n)   fib(n-1) /
> ```

Числа Фибоначчи можно считать как степень матрицы. А степень матрицы считается с помощью [быстрого возведения в степень](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).

Так как нам нужно не само число Фибоначчи а остаток по модулю, то все операции во время возведения в степень тоже будем делать по модулю. Это гарантирует что все числа в вычислениях будут фиксированного размера. Это даст скорость и малое потребление памяти.

Собирая всё вместе:

```
import math
import sys


# a     = F[n     - 1], F[n    ], F[n     + 1]
# b     = F[    m - 1], F[    m], F[    m + 1]
# a * b = F[n + m - 1], F[n + m], F[n + m + 1]
def mul_mod(a, b, m):
    return (
        (a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1]) % m,
        (a[0] * b[1] + a[1] * b[2]) % m,
        (a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[2]) % m
    )


def pow_mod(a, b, m):
    if b == 0:
        return 1, 0, 1
    if b % 2 == 0:
        q = pow_mod(a, b // 2, m)
        return mul_mod(q, q, m)
    return mul_mod(a, pow_mod(a, b - 1, m), m)


def fib_mod(n, m):
    return 0 if n == 0 else pow_mod((0, 1, 1), n - 1, m)[-1]


for line in sys.stdin:
    n, m = map(int, line.split())
    g = math.gcd(n, m)
    print(fib_mod(g, 10 ** 8))
```

P.S. Эта программа прошла все тесты на `e-olymp`. Худшее время теста - 173ms. Покопавшись можно найти решение на Питоне в пять раз (!) быстрее - 36ms. Есть куда стремиться, если учесть что программа читающая и пишущая тысячу строк работает около 26ms. 10ms на вычисления! Вычислительная часть работает быстрее чем моя в 15 раз!

Comment: Здравствуйте, огромное спасибо за проделанный труд. Второй раз уже мне помогаете, искренне благодарю!

Задачка, конечно, сбивает меня  с толку , человека, изучающего python всего 2 месяца)))

Comment: Пожалуйста. Но задача не про Питон. Задача про свойства чисел Фибоначчи. :)

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться той простой идеей, что НОД двух чисел Фибоначчи равен числу Фибоначчи с индексом, равным НОД их индексов (взято с [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0)). Для поиска же n-го числа Фибоначчи по индексу эффективный алгоритм Вам уже [предложил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1347861/464000) @Zhihar.

Также хочу добавить, что интерпретатор Питона – штука достаточно медленная, и не всегда на подобных сайтах гарантируется, что существует решение на Питоне, которое пройдёт по времени; обычно обещают, что такое решение существует на C/C++. В данной задаче требуется вычислить нужное число в худшем случае за 1 мс (1 секунда, 1000 разных больших тестов), и не факт, что есть решение, которое уложится в ограничения.

Кроме того, рекомендую использовать [PyPy](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPy) для скриптов на Питоне в тестирующей системе (если он доступен), особенно для вычислительных задач – в некоторых случаях он существенно ускоряет за счёт предварительной компиляции.

UPD: Спасибо за плюсы, но этот ответ здесь скорее в роли дополнения, чем решения. Заслуженно они должны достаться [подробному объяснению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1347968/464000) @Stanislav Volodarskiy, на мой взгляд :)

Comment: К вашему решению ещё добавить вычисление `F(n)` сразу по модулю `10^8` и задача будет решена за одну секунду даже на Питоне.

Comment: Сегодня вечером на e-olymp будет решение на Питоне. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ждём с нетерпением :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, мне не доводилось писать вычисление больших Фибоначчи, и сейчас не очень много времени на подобные затеи, так что будет здорово, если Вы реализуете

Comment: https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/9802539

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, 173 мс? Потрясающе! Надо же, ~0.2 мс на тест...

Comment: В истории есть решение на Питоне которое в шесть раз быстрее моего. :)

Comment: Наверное, стоит сделать поправку, что Питон чаще не подходит для задач с интенсивным вводом-выводом

Comment: Нет, не надо. 1000 строк читаются и пишутся за 26ms на моём компьютере. Затык не в вводе/выводе.

Answer (score 2):

Что можно предложить

1. использовать матричный способ вычисления числа Фибоначчи:

код:

```
def pow(x, n, I, mult):
    if n == 0:
        return I
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        y = pow(x, n // 2, I, mult)
        y = mult(y, y)
        if n % 2:
            y = mult(x, y)
        return y


def identity_matrix(n):
    r = list(range(n))
    return [[1 if i == j else 0 for i in r] for j in r]


def matrix_multiply(A, B):
    BT = list(zip(*B))
    return [[sum(a * b
                 for a, b in zip(row_a, col_b))
            for col_b in BT]
            for row_a in A]


def fib(n):
    F = pow([[1, 1], [1, 0]], n, identity_matrix(2), matrix_multiply)
    return F[0][1]
```

2. возможно нельзя использовать библиотечные функции и надо написать свою функцию НОД:

код:

```
def _gcd(a, b):
    while a != 0 and b != 0:
        if a > b:
            a = a % b
        else:
            b = b % a

    return a + b
```

или

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while a != b:
        if a > b:
            a = a - b
        else:
            b = b - a

    return a
```

надо посмотреть какой из двух способов работает побыстрее

3. если не использовать матричный способ нахождения чисел Фибоначчи, то тогда 2 числа можно вычислить за 1 проход, ведь одно число меньше второго и значит во время цикла оно тоже будет найдено

для этого можно использовать такой код:

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for __ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

, вернее его модификацию:

```
def fib(n1, n2):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    first = 0
    for i in range(n2):
        a, b = b, a + b
        if i == n1:
            first = a
    return first, a
```

Comment: `F(10^18)` - очень длинное число. Считать надо по модулю.